# me multiplica solo la primera fila de mi tabla

Tags: php, html5

```html
<html>     
     <?php
     include ("conexion.php");
     $productos= "SELECT codigo,descripcion, precioventa,existencia, imagen FROM productos";
     ?>            
<head> 
<title>Formulario</title> 
</head>
<body> 
<table  class="default" border="1">
    <caption>Productos a la Venta</caption>
    <tr>
    <th> Código</th>
    <th> Descripción</th>
    <th> Imagen</th>
    <th> Existencia</th>
    <th> Precio Unitario</th>
    <th> Ingrese Cantidad</th>
    <th> Subtotal</th>
    </tr>
       <?php 
       $resultado =mysqli_query($conexion, $productos);
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){    
        ?> 
  <form method="post" id="myForm"> 
       <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $row["codigo"];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row["descripcion"];?></td>
        <td> <img width="100" src= "imagenes/<?php echo $row['imagen'];?>"></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row["existencia"];?></td>
        <td> <input id= "precio" value="<?php echo $row["precioventa"];?>" disabled> </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="cantidad" min="0" max="<?php echo $row["existencia"];?>" size="1" value="0" > <input type="submit" value="Agregar" id="boton"></td>
        <td id="resultado" class="hide">
     </td>  
          <?php }mysqli_free_result($resultado);?>  
          </tr>  
     </form>    
    </table>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() { 
         $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
              var precio = $("input#precio").val();
              var cantidad = $("input#cantidad").val();
         $.ajax({
                  url:'proceso.php',
                  data: "precio="+precio+"&cantidad="+cantidad,
                  type:  'POST',
                  success:  function (response) {
         $("#resultado").removeClass('hide');
         $("#resultado").html(response);
                   }
                   });
          e.preventDefault();
            });
            });
           </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, soy nueva en esto. Tengo una tabla con datos rescatados de una base de datos que son productos en venta y necesito multiplicar el precio unitario por la cantidad que se ingrese en el input ingrese cantidad al dar click en el botón agregar pero  solo me realiza la operación en la primera línea y no en las otras al hacer click al botón para luego poder sumar los subtotales y hacer un total de los items en donde se realizó la multiplicacion o decir donde cantidad es igual o mayor a 1, he cambiado varias veces mi código y consigo que al hacer click en un solo botón me multiplica en todas los items o solo en la primera linéa como el código que les mostraré.
Para aclarar un poco la idea, puse la imagen del resultado en el navegador, tengo la cantidad 4 en amarillo pero en la columna subtotal no me muestra el resultado después de darle click al botón, pero sí en la primera fila lo realiza.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
<?php 
  
  $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
  $precio =$_POST['precio'];
  $res = $cantidad * $precio;
 
  echo "$".number_format($res);
 
 ?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: al parecer tu problema se base en que no estas manejando el indice del arreglo que esta recorriendo para la construcción de tu tabla.

Comment: Edité el código con las indicaciones que me recomendaste, espero esté más ordenado ahora y agradezco su respuesta sobre los errores. Ojalá puedan ayudarme !

Comment: List! ya lo arreglé.

Comment: El problema que veo es que usas el mismo ID (precio y cantidad) para todas las filas. Los IDs deben ser unicos. Entonces actualizas "#resultado" pero como hay muchas filas con el mismo ID, solo actualiza una de ellas. Yo haria la cuenta con Javascript y luego guardaría con PHP en la BD.

Comment: Hola Alex muchas gracis por responder, tienes razón es el mismo ID, pero es el nombre que le doy a los td para recibir los datos de la base de datos,  que al ingresar más productos tendré más items en mi tabla de ventas y todos serán con el  mismo ID, no entiendo eso de actualizar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diría que estás complicándote la vida intentando usar PHP para una simple operación matemática que puedes hacer con javascript directamente.

- Mira de cambiar esto:

```
var precio = $("input#precio").val(); 
var cantidad = $("input#cantidad").val();
$.ajax({
                  url:'proceso.php',
                  data: "precio="+precio+"&cantidad="+cantidad,
                  type:  'POST',
                  success:  function (response) {
         $("#resultado").removeClass('hide');
         $("#resultado").html(response);
                   }
                   });
```

por esto:

```
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this).find("input[type=submit]:focus" );
    var precio = btn.closest('td').prev('td').find('input').val();
    var cantidad = btn.closest('td').find('input').first().val();
    btn.closest('td').next('td').html("$" + (parseFloat(precio) * parseFloat(cantidad)))
```

Con estas asignaciones nuevas de precio y cantidad prescindimos del uso de los **id** porque estan repetidos en cada ciclo, y los buscamos moviendonos entre los elementos partiendo del botón que lanza la petición.

- Aquí tienes otro problema:

```
<?php 
       $resultado =mysqli_query($conexion, $productos);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){    
        ?> 
  <form method="post" id="myForm">
```

eso lo debes cambiar por esto:

```
  <form method="post" id="myForm"> 
<?php 
       $resultado =mysqli_query($conexion, $productos);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){    
        ?>
```

es decir, debes sacar el inicio del `<form>` del bucle `while` porque lo estás repitiendo constantemente, y en cambio tan solo lo cierras una vez fuera del **while** aquí:

```
<?php }mysqli_free_result($resultado);?>  
          </tr>  
     </form>
```

Aquí dejo un snippet de ejemplo (sin el while pero con datos de ejemplo hardcodeados):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this).find("input[type=submit]:focus");
    var precio = btn.closest('td').prev('td').find('input').val();
    var cantidad = btn.closest('td').find('input').first().val();
    btn.closest('td').next('td').html("$" + (parseFloat(precio) * parseFloat(cantidad)))
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Formulario</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" id="myForm">
    <table class="default" border="1">
      <caption>Productos a la Venta</caption>
      <tr>
        <th> Código</th>
        <th> Descripción</th>
        <th> Imagen</th>
        <th> Existencia</th>
        <th> Precio Unitario</th>
        <th> Ingrese Cantidad</th>
        <th> Subtotal</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> codigo</td>
        <td> descripcion</td>
        <td> <img width="100" src="imagenes/imagen.jpg"></td>
        <td> existencia</td>
        <td> <input id="precio" value="10" disabled> </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="cantidad" min="0" max="10" size="1"> <input type="submit" value="Agregar" id="boton"></td>
        <td id="resultado">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> codigo</td>
        <td> descripcion</td>
        <td> <img width="100" src="imagenes/imagen.jpg"></td>
        <td> existencia</td>
        <td> <input id="precio" value="20" disabled> </td>
        <td><input type="number" id="cantidad" min="0" max="20" size="1"> <input type="submit" value="Agregar" id="boton"></td>
        <td id="resultado">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: lo hice con mi codigo y nada

Comment: este es el pastebin https://pastebin.com/85zNUzAR    ohhh lo siento, no quise sobreescribir la pregunta inicial...lo veré

Comment: Esto es lo que hice, pastebin.com/WhtrrQs6 Le agregué el atributo value="0" a cantidad para que no me arroje "NAN" si se da click al botón agregar sin antes indicar la cantidad. y le cambié la forma al botón de abajo "generar orden de compra".  también al dar click en el botón generar orden me lleva a otra página que es esta https://pastebin.com/NjXtAfYi  aquí ya me genera aleatoriamente el número de la orden de compra y tengo un formulario para llenar datos para la entrega lo que al apretar el botón guardar datos

Comment: así lo dejé, son pocos los cambios https://pastebin.com/8rydWHuy    y este el php que realiza las inserciones a mi base de datos     https://pastebin.com/J0r8VsTn

Comment: ese es donde está el formulario  https://pastebin.com/ESVKMhPs   este es el php   https://pastebin.com/XjeNwSfz

Comment: este es el cambi el archivo php que hice https://pastebin.com/PVnv5nmV

Comment: lo otro que hace, es cuando elijo solamente un items, pasa a la siguiente etapa. genero la orden y cuando voy a la base, me ingresa de una todos los productos incluso los que no he selccionado

Comment: estamos hablando asincronamente, jeje... tu vas por un lado y yo por el otro... vamos por partes y responde solo a lo que te pregunto: 1) ¿has cambiado los dos scripts o solo uno?  Estas son las últimas versiones que debes usar: https://pastebin.com/1KgG0Mfe y https://pastebin.com/niPJFTZX     Cuando las estes usando a la vez deberia funcionarte bien

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente tu ayuda y con este caso que lo quiero seguir puliendo y agregando más cositas, he entendido hartas cosas por ejemplo que las matrices deben convertirse en array y que igual debo poner el uso de sesiones en cada página que hago para que el supuesto usuario no entre como pedro por su casa a cada página sin hacer inicio de la sesión jajajjajaj

Comment: y aplicar de buena forma la identación, ser ordenada en eso

Comment: tengo brackets que es donde escribo mis códigos, es botón tidy ...se usa cómo?

Comment: ahh ya lo encontré jsfiddle.net

Comment: no borres estos en donde están los link por favor, que me los estudiaré sí o si, y claro estaba viendo jsfiddle.net y es bastante práctico, lo usaré también

Comment: si el sublime con visualcode igual los tengo, pero se me hizo mas amigable brackets, entonces guardaré en mis notas los link de las páginas que me recomendaste. estoy estudiando y a la vez me  voy ganando cursos en el instituto y los hago, ahora me gané una beca para un curso de ciberseguridad, jajajajaj mi vida se basa en estudiar casi....me gusta este campo de la programación y todos sus misterios, amigo muchas gracias por todo y no sé si pueda ayudarte en algo, sé que sabes muchísimo más que yo, pero estoy por si puedo aportar en algo

Comment: Tranquila, ya me has aportado retos y fitas conseguidas, con eso me doy por pagado, y yo tambien aprendo sobre la marcha con ellos y programo mejor :-)  Ahora veo que si quisiera podria montar un amazon en dos dias gracias a lo que hemos hecho para tu proyecto xD

Comment: jajajajaajajajaj verdad, podrías hacerlo jajajajjaja, gracias por ser tan amable y claro para explicar, que estos temas son un poco complejos de entender a la primera

Comment: Hola, puedo molestarte con una pregunta?

Comment: Te he dado una respuesta a tu otra pregunta, supongo que era eso lo que querias. Ya me dirás si te funciona (no lo he probado)